# client.create_hours_of_operation fails with AttributeError: 'Connect' object has no attribute 'create_hours_of_operation'

Tags: boto3

client.create_hours_of_operation fails with AttributeError: 'Connect' object has no attribute 'create_hours_of_operation'
Any help appreciated

out of the doc
response = client.create_hours_of_operation(

```
    InstanceId='xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',
    Name='SunMonTueWedThuFriSat008to1700',
    Description='SunMonTueWedThuFriSat008to1700',
    TimeZone='Australia/Melbourne',
    Config=[
        {
            'Day': 'SUNDAY'|'MONDAY'|'TUESDAY'|'WEDNESDAY'|'THURSDAY'|'FRIDAY'|'SATURDAY',
            'StartTime': {
                'Hours': 8,
                'Minutes': 0
            },
            'EndTime': {
                'Hours': 17,
                'Minutes': 00
            }
        },
    ]
)
```

Comment: What exactly is `client`?

Answer (score 0):

needed to upgrade boto3. Seems it is a recent feature